# What's the name of params for Nested Resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nested-forms, restful-url

I have a nested resources like this

```
resources :profiles do
    resources :albums do
      resources :images 
    end
  end
match ':username' => "profiles#show", :as => 'profile'
```

so as example the url of specific image is

```
http://localhost:3000/profiles/Azzurrio/albums/4/images/1
```

I can't use profile username inside my template, when I use params[:username] it doesn't work, so can anyone tell me how can I deal with this params?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[This page](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) (look for "nested routes") tells you what you want.

In short, if you have the nested resource structure you've defined above, then the url will contain this structure:

`profiles/:profile_id/albums/:album_id/images/:image_id`

So you're looking for `params[:profile_id]`

Answer (score 3):

If you run `rake routes` it will also tell you the names of the various param keys.

Comment: I did not know that.  Interesting!